# fetching is null records from case statement where clasue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i want to fetch Category IS NULL  records WHEN 'S' , im not able to get it with the following case statement

```
 USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
 GO
 DECLARE @Cat VARCHAR(5)
 SET @Cat='S' 
 SELECT   ProductNumber,ProductName where Category =
  CASE @Cat
     WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
     WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
     WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
     WHEN 'S' THEN 'NULL'
     ELSE 'Not for sale'
  END,
  Name
 FROM Production.Product
 ORDER BY ProductNumber;
 GO
```

what im trying to get is the following query

```
  DECLARE @Cat VARCHAR(5)
  SET @Cat='S' 
  SELECT   ProductNumber,ProductName where Category is null
```

here @Cat is my input parameter which comes from my GUI

Answer (score 1):

Remove `WHEN 'S' THEN 'NULL'` in your code and add this predicate:

```
OR (Category is null and @Cat = 'S')
```